# How can I bind a CommandParameter with a child UserControl's child element?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I have the following xaml view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyViews.PersonView"
  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyViews"
 [...]
>
[...]
<dxb:BarManager x:Name="MainBarManager">
  <dxb:BarManager.Items>
    <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="bbiPrint"
                       Content="{Binding Print, Source={StaticResource CommonResources}}" 
                       Command="{Binding PrintPersonsCommand}" 
                       CommandParameter="{Binding PersonsCardView, ElementName=CardUserControl}"
                       />
  </dxb:BarManager.Items>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    [...]
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <views:CardView x:Name="CardUserControl" Grid.Row="2"/>
  </Grid>
[...]
</UserControl>
```

The `CardView` is defined as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyViews.CardView"
             [...]>
[...]

    <dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPersons}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="MultipleRow">
        [...]
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:CardView x:Name="PersonsCardView" 
                          [...]
                          CardTemplate="{StaticResource DisplayCardTemplate}" 
                          PrintCardViewItemTemplate="{StaticResource PrintCardTemplate}"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        [...]
    </dxg:GridControl>
</UserControl>
```

The `PrintPersonsCommand` is defined as follows in my ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
  public PersonViewModel(...)
  {
    [...]
    PrintPersonsCommand = new Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand<DataViewBase>(PrintPersons, CanPrintPersons);
  }  

  public Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand<DataViewBase> PrintPersonsCommand { get; private set; }

  private void PrintPersons(DataViewBase view)
  {
    _printService.ShowGridViewPrintPreview(view);
  }

  private bool CanPrintPersons(DataViewBase view)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now, when I click the Print button, the above `PrintPersons` method is always fed with `null`. How do I pass `CardUserControl.PersonsCardView` in my `MyViews.PersonView` xaml above, how do I pass that `PersonCardView` to my command? In other words, how do I fix

```
CommandParameter="{Binding PersonsCardView, ElementName=CardUserControl}"
```

to make it work?

Currently, the only solution I've found to this problem is to replace the `Command` and `CommandParameter` with

```
ItemClick="OnPrintBtnClick"
```

and then in the `PersonView`'s code-behind file to do:

```
private void OnPrintBtnClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  var ctxt = DataContext as PersonViewModel;
  ctxt.PrintPersonsCommand.Execute(CardUserControl.PersonsCardView);
}
```

That works but I can't believe there is no other way. I'm not happy with that solution because I don't have the benefits of using the `Command` any more, like e.g. the automatic evaluation of the Command's `CanExecute` method. I could also put the `CardView`'s xaml code in the `PersonView.xaml` but I like my controls to be in separate files because I have the feeling it's more structured and each user control has its own responsibilities which can nicely be split into separate files. Also, that solution binds my view to my view model too tightly.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: What do you need the parameter for? I.e. what's in the `PersonsCardView` that's not in the `PersonViewModel`?

Comment: I want to print the cards of my card view. I have other views, like a grid view. The `PersonViewModel` has no information about that `PersonsCardView`. It only carries the necessary logic to print a view. I don't want the `PersonViewModel` to have any kind of information on the view to be printed. It would bind the view model to the view too tightly.

Comment: My `PersonView`'s child views (like `CardView` mentioned above and `GridView` not mentioned above) all share the same view model.

Comment: Fair point, but _passing the view as parameter to the view model_  looks like the tightest coupling I can imagine, already.

Comment: No, because I am passing an abstraction of it. Both the `CardView` and the `GridView` inherit from `DataViewBase`. I do not expect any of the views used in my app to be of a different type.

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your existing view and viewmodel hierarchy, I was able to pass the GridControl.View to the PersonViewModel using the **Tag** property
You can assign the CardView to the Tag property at the bottom of your CardView UserControl, and then access this Tag as CommandParameter.

**CardView UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyViews.CardView"
         [...]>
    [...]

<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPersons}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="MultipleRow">
    [...]
    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:CardView x:Name="PersonsCardView" 
                      [...]
                      CardTemplate="{StaticResource DisplayCardTemplate}" 
                      PrintCardViewItemTemplate="{StaticResource PrintCardTemplate}"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
    [...]
</dxg:GridControl>

<UserControl.Tag>
    <Binding ElementName="PersonsCardView"/>
</UserControl.Tag>

</UserControl>
```

**Print Button Xaml:**

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="bbiPrint"
                   Content="{Binding Print, Source={StaticResource CommonResources}}" 
                   Command="{Binding PrintPersonsCommand}" 
                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CardUserControl, Path=Tag}"
                   />
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Is that way to proceed a standard in WPF or am I doing my stuff in the wrong way? Is there a better way to organize my UserControls?

Comment: Passing a UI Control to the viewmodel is generally not encouraged in MVVM. If we have to just print the view, then we could do it in code behind, as printing a control has nothing to do with the viewmodel. Or, If printing has to be initiated in the viewmodel, then I would have placed the Print command in the CardViewModel. It would make the passing of the UI element much more cleaner just by using CommandParameter as binding.

Comment: I think I get your point; I'll post an answer with my understanding of your both suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Based on the valuable input of Insane, I came up with the following two cleaner fixes:

## Code-behind solution

In the `PersonView`, use the `ItemClick` event handler on the `Print` button:

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="bbiPrint"
  Content="{Binding Print, Source={StaticResource CommonResources}}" 
  ItemClick="OnPrintBtnClick"/>
```

Adapt the corresponding code-behind file like this:

```
public partial class PersonView : UserControl
{
  readonly IPrintService _printService;

  public PersonView(IPrintService printService)
  {
    _printService = printService;

    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void OnPrintBtnClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
  {
    _printService.ShowGridViewPrintPreview(CardUserControl.PersonsCardView);
  }
}
```

Because I want to gray-out the Print button when there is no selection, I still need to add some code to make that happen. I can get it by 
1. updating the button code to

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="bbiPrint"
  Content="{Binding Print, Source={StaticResource CommonResources}}" 
  ItemClick="OnPrintBtnClick" IsEnabled="{Binding CanPrintPersons}"/>
```

2. refreshing the `CanPrintPersons` property in the `PersonViewModel` upon Persons selection change

That's it.

## CardViewModel solution

In that solution, we have a `PersonView` with its underlying `PersonViewModel` and a `CardView` with its underlying `CardViewModel`. I will not describe that solution with all the details as it is overkill in my situation but for the sake of completeness, I'll give the main points. Upon clicking the `Print` button on the `PersonView`, the `PersonViewModel`'s `PrintCommand` is called. That command emits a `Print` event to the `CardViewModel` which in turn calls its own `PrintCommand`. That latter command calls

```
_printService.ShowGridViewPrintPreview(View);
```

where the `View` is a `CardViewModel`'s property that is set upon `CardView` loading with e.g.

```
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="Loaded" Command="{Binding ViewLoadedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PersonsCardView}" />
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Because I have two child views I want to print, I'd need to add a view model for each one of those. In addition, those two view models plus the `PersonViewModel` need access to the list of Persons to be printed. In particular, they need a shared access to the same data, so that they are synchronized. A simple way to do that is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430434/sharing-collection-between-viewmodels) and is totally doable. But I think it is not worth the trouble for the simple use case I have as it adds more complexity than necessary.